# apache spawning too many processes despite maxclient and other constraints

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

Here are my MPM constraints:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers         10
    MinSpareServers      10
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients           10
    MaxRequestsPerChild  2000
</IfModule>
```

However despite this, I have over 20 apache processes running currently, and in the past hour or two there have been as many as 40-50.  Shouldn't the MaxClient and MaxSpareServers keep the number of processes under control (i.e. about 10)?

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Two questions: Are you changing the correct config file? Did you restart apache after this change?

Comment: Yes.  I'm changing apache2.conf, theres nothing in my httpd.conf.  And yes, i restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Apache comes in different flavours, two of the most common being *prefork* and *worker*. The prefork model spawns several processes but each process handles only one request at a time. The worker model, on the other hand, spawns several processes and each process has multiple threads, each thread handling one request at a time.

Depending on your distribution you may be running a different model to that which you are expecting. You are expecting prefork but are you sure this is the type that is running? To find out type:

```
$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   May 28 2010 07:58:25
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

In this case my `Server MPM` is `Prefork` but yours may be different. On my Debian server running Apache2 it is `Worker`:

```
# /usr/sbin/apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)
Server MPM:     Worker
```

On some machines (such as RedHat) it is not uncommon for both prefork and worker binaries to be present (one called `httpd` and another called `httpd.worker` or something similar). You may want to double-check (using `ps` or `top` or `cat /etc/init.d/httpd`) which is actually being launched.

Comment: This. Also, prefork is a memory hog so I would use Worker where possible. Though you may need to verify that Worker is stable when combined with your modules.

Comment: People often use prefork with modules that cannot be threaded such as mod_perl.

Comment: Thanks for your reply PP.  I'm definitely using Prefork.  Any reason why there's more processes running than what I specified in my config?

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, there is another potential cause.**

I know you believe you've already found your answer but with prefork you should see the same thing either way you look at it's processes. You must not have been using prefork.

This is why:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html

> This
>   Multi-Processing Module (MPM) implements a non-threaded, pre-forking
>   web server.

---

**A different explanation that I've run into**

Loading the prefork module before the configuration options works, but if you load it after it seems to load some defaults instead, rendering your IfModule directive inert. You will likely only see this on a customized apache config, as distributions would have it setup correctly to start.

**Works** - configuration is applied

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers         1
MinSpareServers      1
MaxSpareServers      0
ServerLimit          4
MaxClients           4
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

**Doesn't work** - configuration has no effect

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers         1
MinSpareServers      1
MaxSpareServers      0
ServerLimit          4
MaxClients           4
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

Comment: THIS! Thank you! I've been beating my head on this for a few days now and it was because I put the config before it loaded the module.

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of stupid now, but this: [Why does htop show lots of apache2 processes by ps aux doesn't?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24198/why-does-htop-show-lots-of-apache2-processes-by-ps-aux-doesnt) explains my problem.

Comment: WIth prefork you should see the same thing either way. `This Multi-Processing Module (MPM) implements a non-threaded, pre-forking web server.` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html