# Why do I see many mongod processes running?

Tags: top, mongodb, htop

I am running a single MongoDB database. No sharding. When I run htop, I see a lot of instances of mongod. Is that normal? Does every connection create a separate mongod process? Should I be concerned?

For some reason when I use top, only one of them is shown. That part is confusing also.

As asked in the comments, output of "ps axjf | grep mongod":

```
12858 12878 12877 12858 pts/0    12877 S+     500   0:00              \_ grep mongod
1  2691  2690  2690 ?           -1 Sl     497  70:54 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: Please append the output of `ps axjf | grep mongod` to your question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/24198/why-does-htop-show-lots-of-apache2-processes-by-ps-aux-doesnt) .. htop is showing different threads as well. not just processes. top and ps show only processes.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer.

Comment: You can hide threads in htop. Press F2 to go the settings, go to Display Options, and select "Hide kernel threads" and "Hide userland process threads". To still show the threads, but in a different color, select "Display threads in a different color".